# MAMP - localhost is redirect to an unknow IP address

Tags: php, apache, mamp

I started Apache, when I visited with `http://locahost`, it's been redirected to http://123.57.14.229 (this IP once configured in DB, but I changed it to `127.0.0.1` in my local database).

As I checked with `lsof -i:80`, it shows below.

What does it mean in the green frame?

[image]

I even tried droping the database and restarted the computer, but this issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

I found about Bogon-s on wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogon_filtering

And also that IP looks like a real live IP when pinging it,

```
PING 123.57.14.229 (123.57.14.229): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 123.57.14.229: icmp_seq=0 ttl=99 time=336.692 ms
```

So I would probably say you have some kind of software installed that cause this redirection. Did you tried running apache on different port maybe? Just for testing?

Comment: Yes, actually, that's the IP we used once, now it's out of service for us. I tried changing the port to 8088, then it will be redirected to an URL related to this IP (the domain for this IP). What's the possible cause you think it would be?

Comment: What it shows in Firefox? What is in your index.php? Is that loading and redirects? If not, we need to find the problem in your server settings. If loading, we need to see the code.
Can you show me the networking tab from Chrome when loading localhost?

Comment: It shows blank before, after I changed the port to 8088 and then changed it back to 80 again, it shows the same page as Chrome does.

Comment: Can you show me the networking tab from Chrome when loading localhost and index.php?